# Cannot simulate a moving location in iOS simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios-simulator

I'm trying to simulate a moving location (freeway drive) on the ios simulator, however it simply doesn't work. The only location that works is the static `Custom Location...` option.

To reproduce the problem:

1. open up `Xcode>open developer tools>simulator`,
2. open up the maps app
3. set `debug>location` to "Freeway Drive"
4. press the location button in the bottom left corner

It loads for a while, then says:

```
Current Location Not Available
Your current location cannot be determined at this time
```

When I open up `system.log`, I see the message:

`SimulatorBridge[41185]: Selected location simulation scenario does not exist`

I'm using Xcode 7.1.1 and the iPhone 6s / iOS 9.1 simulator. I've tried:

1. Setting a default location
2. Resetting the simulator in `Simulator>Reset Content and Settings...`
3. Reinstalling the simulator

but nothing seems to work. Anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try opening the app first?  Don't do `Xcode>open developer tools>simulator` at all; set the location in the Simulator...Debug...Location menu.

Comment: Hi, yeah I've tried opening my test app first as well as setting the location under `Debug>Location`, but nothing seems to work (except custom). I'm using `SwiftLocation` installed with cocoapods (which calls requestAlwaysAuthorization and requestWhenInUseAuthorization as needed) and I've set both `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` and `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` in my Info.plist, but no luck.

Comment: There have been several similar problems reported on SO the last few weeks.  The only proposed solution is to run on a actual test device, not the simulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, this may be a problem on Apple's end with Simulator for iOS 9.1.

I downloaded the iOS 9.0 simulator instead (`Xcode>Preference>Downloads`), fired up Maps in Simulator with the location set to `Freeway Drive`, and everything works -the location updates.

If you've had trouble simulating a moving location in your own app, just download and use a previous iOS Simulator version like above. Make sure you clean your project in Xcode first (`Product>Clean`), then rebuild it and everything should work fine.